# How to let random users add a card to a public Trello board?

Tags: trello

I want to use a public Trello board as a public suggestion box. Optimally, I'd include the link in a blog post in the header of my website, and I'd ask users to "add a card" for each unique suggestion.

Unfortunately, at the moment it appears Trello users (who are not members of a board) cannot create cards on public boards. They can only comment on cards themselves.

Is there any way around this? Is there any way to allow all Trello users to create cards on a public Trello board?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trello now offers an invite collaborators by URL feature (currently in beta).

**Steps**

1. Show Menu
2. Add Members > `Invite people by giving them a special link…`
3. Place the URL in a conspicuous place like your website or a Readme card of some sort along with some instructions for your collaborators.

**Demo**

[image: Demo of Trello's Invite by URL]

Answer (score 6):

Based on how Trello boards are set up, you cannot. Trello works by letting the organization creator add new users to the group.

These are the only options available to a Trello User not attached to a organization (based on your profile settings)

- Visibility
- Voting
- Comments

See this feature request for more information [Allow non-users to propose cards](https://trello.com/card/allow-non-users-to-propose-cards/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/479)

Comment: I get the "private" error for that link.   What's the status on that card?

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at https://waffle.io. They do what you're looking to do, and they sync with GitHub issues.

Comment: Please try to elaborate on your answer as per site rules [answer]