# How can a viewer request access to a board in Trello?

Tags: trello

I'm creating a public Trello board that I would like others to contribute to.   However, when I log into the board as a different user, I don't see any sort of "request access" link.   I could tell people to email me to get access to the board, but that's kind of clunky.  Is there a better way?

The best would be this feature request:  [How to let random users add a card to a public Trello board?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24887/how-to-let-random-users-add-a-card-to-a-public-trello-board).   Some sort of moderation queue, in other words.   But a prominent "request an invitation" link would be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way to do this would be to put an email address in the description that would allow them to contact you.

I'm going to also post this to the 'feature request' trello board, as I have encountered it, in the past.
https://trello.com/card/users-can-request-an-invite-to-a-board/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/1368

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was adding a card that said "If you comment on this card or any other card, I will give you public access to this board."

Comment: I did this too. Link back to the feature too, so people commenting can vote on it!